# Failed to read the request form. Request body too large. The max request body size is 30000000 bytes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I know many questions have already answered this. But they either answer it for [Kestrel or IIS configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62987343/request-body-too-large), or [per action and not globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74005408/c-unable-to-write-data-to-the-transport-connection-broken-pipe-when-using-res).

I want to be able to upload large files in my ASP.NET Core API.

I'm running my API using `dotnet Api.dll`, and it's behind an Nginx reverse proxy. I guess this means that I'm not using Kestrel.

Then I have this config in my `Startup.cs`:

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
{
    x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
});
```

And it does not work. I get this error:

> Failed to read the request form. Request body too large. The max request body size is 30000000 bytes

What should I do?

Comment: And how have you configured Nginx

Comment: Either redesign you code to split the request into smaller pieces or use a different tool that can handle larger request.  Your current tool has a max limit that cannot be changed.

Comment: @Charlieface, Nginx is OK now. I have added `client_max_body_size 0;`

Comment: @jdweng you mean .NET 7 can not handle half a gigabyte upload?

Comment: Please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads).

Comment: You are sending an HTTP request where max limits are often set at a server and these limits may be in OS and not able to be exceeded in application software.

Comment: @jdweng, that's why I ask. To see if it can be configured or not.

Comment: @JHBonarius, I read that. It has only one section that explains about IIS. My code runs on Linux and it's behind Nginx reverse proxy. I can't find the answer in that doc link.

Comment: You're probably still using Kestrel, even when you're using nginx as a reverse proxy. Where you need to configure the limit depends on where the error comes from. If you are getting an exception from .NET then it's not coming from nginx.

Comment: Ok, I missed your code, so I didn't understand you were already using a multipart stream to upload your file. Weird, that always seemed to work for me, even on Kestrel with big files.

Comment: I'm not sure if the error caused by nginx, Maybe you can refer to this [Docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-management-suite/acm/how-to/policies/request-body-size-limit/).

Comment: If you're running behind nginx, that means you're probably using Kestrel as an application server. That's the default. You cannot use nginx without an application server with ASP.NET Core. Long story short - use the Kestrel guide to increase the request body size limit.

Answer (score 2):

change the ConfigureKestrel option

ex)

```
options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 50 * 1024 * 1024;
```